# Can I run Sublime Text 2 from SSH on Ubuntu?

Tags: ipad, ubuntu, ssh

I'm trying to find the best way I can program using my iPad, I'm relatively new to ubuntu and I don't no it's limitations over SSH but I was curious to know if it were possible to install a text editor for instance Sublime Text 2 and open it using a SSH terminal from my iPad using iSSH.

Thanks a lot

Comment: If the iPad had an X server, you could have used X-forwarding. However, the iPad doesn't (and I doubt Apple would allow one in their store) so it's not possible.

Comment: I've jailbroken my iPad so perhaps I'll have a look in the cydia store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[iSSH](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/issh-ssh-vnc-console/id287765826?mt=8) ($9.99 on the US store) has an X server built in. You can install Sublime on your Ubuntu box and use iSSH to access it.

Comment: Are there any modifications I need to make or will it work out of the box?

Comment: You'd need to configure it correctly. See http://www.zinger-soft.com/support_a_4.html for details.

Comment: I've just setup a linode Ubuntu 12.04 server but it looks like I have to install a GUI like unity for this to work.

Comment: I think Sublime just depends on GTK, so you might be able to get away with installing GTK and the X libraries. Good luck.